# php twitter post message with oauth

Tags: php, twitter

is any simple methods to work with my twitter-account in my php app? any Internet samples show how to work with any different accounts (with web-page allow-deny), but i need use only my twitter account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth uses the new oauth authentication

Comment: this method needs to auth(get secret tocken) my php app before it can post in twitter, so i wonder can i get this secret token by manyally login in my account?

Comment: @kusanagi You need to create a dev.twitter.com app. Then you feed in your consumer_token and consumer_secret_token from the app to twitteroauth. Once twitteroauth has generated request and then access tokens, you can store the access tokens for easy later use.

Comment: so without creating dev.twitter.com app and feed consumer_token and consumer_secret_token i can't use my own twitter account?

Comment: @kusanagi Since August 2010 this is the case. Refer to http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth. This is for the REST API. You can use the GET search API without authentication.

Comment: @brian_d after you create an app you can get the access token for your account using following this guide: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token

Answer (score 3):

This tutorial will lead through the process of tweeting to your own account using PHP and OAuth:

http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-tutorials/hello-twitter-oauth-php/

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: You are totally correct, Twitter requires you to have Oauth,and this is a little more robust than the other code. [Here](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)'s another code example that does use Oauth.

Comment: as i know twitter now works only with oauth, i wonder may be i can get manually secret token from my account to use it in php app

Comment: that 'solution' does not use oauth, but the now obsolete basic authentication